# Retrieving Subscriber amount from YouTube using File Get Contents

Tags: php, dom, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get the live amount of YouTube subscribers for a clients YouTube channel. I have registered a public API key and enabled the YouTube Data API.

How do I go about getting the exact number of subscribers on the page?
- I have been trying to use file_get_contents and search for the span class but nothing is working. I have not used this function before.
- Having seen examples from YouTube API v2, it should probably be very easy to use V3 but I have no idea!
- The reason I am asking about both API and File_get_contents, is because if I can use file_get_contents and learn to use it, I can complete numerous other tasks along with it, so two solutions would be perfect!!

Before any criticism, I have searched the internet all the way back to 2010 for my answer. It could just be a problem on my end, but hopefully some solutions will arise...

```
            $page = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/user/user here');
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($page);

        if (!$dom->loadHTML($page)) {
            die ('Could not parse...');
        }

        $divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span');
        foreach($divs as $div) {
            if ($div->getAttribute('aria-labelledby') === 'yt-uix-tooltip84-arialabel') {
                 echo $div->nodeValue;
            }
        }
```

The subscription number is held in a span:

```
<span class="yt-subscription-button-subscriber-count-branded-horizontal yt-uix-tooltip" title="210,089" tabindex="0" aria-label="210,089 subscribers" data-tooltip-text="210,089" aria-labelledby="yt-uix-tooltip84-arialabel">210,089</span>
```

Comment: Parsing the page isn't the good way to do. Use API V3 with example https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/